# Loading a view from 3D Touch shortcut menu

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have added a 3D Touch app shortcut for my app, but when tapping on it, the app crashes with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Something is nil, though I'm not sure what/why as I have this code working in another app. The only difference I can see is this new app uses Core Data.

```
    private func selectTabBarItemForIdentifier(identifier: ShortcutIdentifier) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc = UIViewController()

    switch (identifier) {
    case .AddItem:
        // load AddItem view directly
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddItemController") as! AddItemController
    }
    window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true;

}
```

The "window!" is of course an optional, though this isn't an issue in my other app and I don't believe it to be the culprit here. Again, I suspect something with Core Data, but I have been unable to find anything on StackOverflow or elsewhere specific to this situation.

I've also tried changing the view that loads, but I still get that nil error.

Here's CoreData-related code:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.group.TestApp" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TestApp", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway - check `window` for nil.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not nil.

Comment: Well, in your code above - which line causes a crash?

Comment: The "window!.rootViewController...." line, but the same error occurs even when the app is already open, so the window should have context/not be nil.

Comment: Have you tried `window?` syntax?

Comment: Yes, same error unfortunately. I don't know if it helps, but this is where it shows the issue: 0x1001da5dc <+44>:  brk    #0x1

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets try to unwrap an optional, replace

```
window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with:

```
if let aWindow = window {
    aWindow.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Same error. It's all data at that breakpoint, like persistentStoreCoordinator.storage, storyboard, aWindow, none of any values of nil. Again, the only difference between the app that works and this one is this one is using Core Data and the other has no persistence.

Comment: Could you update your start post - it seems that CoreData related code is missed.

Comment: Sure thing, added. For what it's worth, the app is functional, I can add, edit and delete items and the changes persist through app being killed/relaunched.